# Функция копирования массива

Tags: javascript

нужно реализовать функцию copy(list) по копированию массива.
Предусмотреть возможность передачи вторым аргументом функции. При копировании массива – функция применяется к каждому элементу копируемого массива.

```
newList = copy(list, function(value){ return value*10; })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так и передавайте в функцию `copy` массив и дополнительную функцию, а в самой функции в созданный новый массив заносите элементы `list` прошедшие через функцию `func`.

Например вот так:

```js
function copy(list, func){
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        result[i] = func(list[i]);
    return result;
}

let list = [1,2,3];
let newList = copy(list, function(value){return value * 10;});

console.log(list);
console.log(newList);
```

Или можно вот так:

```
function copy(list, func){
    return list.map(func);
}
```